# how to grab a substring between a character and a string in powershell using regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a variable $s that holds a filepath and an error based on piping a get-childitem to selecting a pattern in a string. the output looks something like this:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\testpoint.txt:15906:  Error: an error has been logged.
```

where

```
$s = C:\Users\admin\Desktop\testpoint.txt:15906:  Error: an error has been logged.
```

Now what I want to do is select the string between \ and .txt (IE, the output in this example is *testpoint*) and output it as a secondary variable. 'regex::Matches' is what will allow me to do this from what I have researched, but the syntax is what is killing me. so far this is what i attempted:

```
 [regex]::Matches($s, '\([^/)]+).txt')
```

but, it errors out. **How do I go about getting whatever is between two constraints, in this case the constraints being the character " \ " and the string ".txt?"**

Comment: It's probably a better idea to fix the problem at its source, instead of using regex to extract the output from another regex operation. `Get-ChildItem ... |Select-String -Pattern $pattern |ForEach-Object { (Get-Item -LiteralPath $_.Path).BaseName }` would have given you just the matched file's name sans the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[regex]::Match($s, '[^\\]+(?=\.txt)').value
```

The regex will match

- `[^\\]+` - one or more chars other than `\`
- `(?=\.txt)` - that are immediately followed with `.txt`.

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E%5C%5C%5D%2B%28%3F%3D%5C.txt%29&i=C%3A%5CUsers%5Cadmin%5CDesktop%5Ctestpoint.txt%3A15906%3A%20%20Error%3A%20an%20error%20has%20been%20logged.).

**Another idea:** cut at the second `:` and parse the file name without extension:

```
[io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(($s -replace '^([^:]*:[^:]*):.*', '$1'))
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%5B%5E%3A%5D*%3A%5B%5E%3A%5D*%29%3A.*&i=C%3A%5CUsers%5Cadmin%5CDesktop%5Ctestpoint.txt%3A15906%3A%20%20Error%3A%20an%20error%20has%20been%20logged.&r=%241). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^:]*:[^:]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `:`, a `:`, and again zero or more chars other than `:`
- `:` - a `:` char
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use a single [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation:

```
PS> $s = 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\testpoint.txt:15906:  Error: an error has been logged.'
    $s -replace '^.+\\([^.]+)\..+$', '$1'
testpoint
```

---

But, as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, it's probably easier to extract this information via *properties* from the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) *objects* output by [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string), which your sample output suggests you're dealing with, along the lines of:

```
PS> Select-String -List 'Error:' *.log | Split-Path -LeafBase
testpoint
```

- `-List` limits the searches to at most 1 match per file.
- The `MatchInfo` output objects have a `.Path` property reflecting the path of the file in which a match was found, and that property binds to `Split-Path`'s `-Path` parameter via the pipeline.

Note: The `-LeafBase` parameter of the [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path) cmdlet requires [PowerShell (Core) v7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), and isn't supported in *Windows PowerShell*; there you can use:

```
PS> Select-String -List 'Error:' *.log | ForEach-Object {
      [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Path)
    }
testpoint
```